# How to correctly link between different Views

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a `master.cshtml` with a navigation bar. My first link is to another view, `ProjectManagement`

```
<li><a href="~/Views/ProjectManagement.cshtml">Project Management</a></li>
```

`master.cshtml` is in `/Views/Shared/_master.cshtml`

`ProjectManagement` is in `/Views/ProjectManagement.cshtml`

Whenever I click on the link I get:

> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /Views/ProjectManagement.cshtml

Am I using the wrong path or should I try to access the page differently?

**Edit:** I was able to get close by using this:

```
<a href="@Html.Action( "ProjectMgmt", "Service", "Project Management" )">
```

The only problem is that it now puts the page into my navigation bar! I only want it to link to page, what could I be doing this time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't link to directly to views, you link to actions. Actions are implemented as methods on a controller; these methods are located using the routing system.

Example Controller:

```
public class ServicesController : Controller 
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ProjectManagement()
    {
         // automatically locates the correct view; you can also explicitly
         // pass the path to the view
         return View();
    }
}
```

You can now right-click on the action method name ("ProjectManagement") and select "Add View". This will help you create a new view, and put it in a location which can be automatically found by the view engine.

Views are typically placed in a "Views/[ControllerName]/" folder, e.g. "Views/Services/ProjectManagement.cshtml".

To link to this action method in your navigation bar, you can use the helper method `ActionLink()`.

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink( "Project Management", "ProjectManagement", "Services" )</li>
```

See also: [Controllers and Routing](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/controllers-and-routing)

Comment: Thank you for answering, after creating a new services controller and creating a view from here, I went on to add the Action method you posted, I am getting an error here though.

Comment: The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController.

Source Error: 
Line 29:                         <li>@Html.Action( "Project Management", "ProjectManagement", "Services" )</li>

Comment: Hmm...I assume you recompiled the project after adding the controller? This can also be caused by changes to the routing table or adding multiple areas to the MVC site. If you don't find something obvious, I'd suggest creating a second blank project just to experiment with this.