# Html.Action is not creating link to View

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I'm trying to get a navigation bar going for my website but I am having some trouble.

I have the following:

```
<li>@Html.Action( "Project Management", "ProjectManagement", "Services" )</li>
```

Set up to call the view, but what it seems to be doing is placing that view into the navigation bar.

Is this the proper way to link the view to the navigation bar or should I try something different?

Comment: I imagine that this is in regards to my [earlier answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135770/mvc-href-view-to-view/16135831#16135831). I fixed my code sample (and Jesse's answer is correct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to use is [`@Html.ActionLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink.aspx) rather than [`@Html.Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703423.aspx).

- `@Html.ActionLink` Generates a hyperlink, `<a href="...">Text</a>`
- `@Html.Action` Executes a Controller action, i.e., returns the HTML/markup/JSON/whatever, that it's programmed to return.

---

Try this code instead:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink( "Project Management", "ProjectManagement", "Services" )</li>
```

Comment: Ah well that makes perfect sense! Thank you very much!